# If expression evaluates to false and skips over elseif to else

Tags: php, if-statement, phpstorm

It seems that for some reason when the expression for if returns false it skips over my elseif and goes straight to else. I tried to figure out something weird but my basic test still fails. What gives? I would like to add that I am using php 5.4 built in for debugging and using phpstorm if that matters.

```
$value = 2;

if ($value == 0) {
    xdebug_var_dump($value);
} elseif ($value == 1) {
    xdebug_var_dump($value);
} else {
    xdebug_var_dump($value);
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it's skipping over the `elseif`?

Comment: using phpstorm you can see it while using xdebug and stepping into each line. There must be something in the if statement that checks the following elseif statements to see if they return true but while stepping it steps over elseif as if it was not even looking at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `else if` is also false (since 1 != 2), so your code skips over to the `else`.

```
$value = 1;

if ($value == 0) {
    xdebug_var_dump($value);
} else if ($value == 1) {
    // This should run:
    xdebug_var_dump($value);
} else {
    xdebug_var_dump($value);
}
```

Comment: Must be a bug in phpstorm then. It doesn't actually show it evaluating the elseif expression but if it is true it will jump to that section. Thats annoying because it made me think it was not evaluating it at all.

Answer (score 2):

It is expected. Your else if condition evaluates to False and thus it skips to else block.

This example should illustrate it:

```
<?php
$value = 2;

if($value == 0){
    echo "if block was executed";
} 
elseif($value == 1){ // 2 !== 1
    echo "elseif block 1 was executed";
} 
elseif($value == 2){
    echo "elseif block 2 was executed";
}
else{
    echo "else block was executed";
}
?>
```

This outputs:

```
elseif block 2 was executed
```

Hope this helps.